# Difference between using list.reverse and list = list[::-1] in python

Tags: python, list

I'm writing an algorithm that rotates a square matrix 90º degrees in-place, without using a second matrix. It works, but I've got one small problem that is troubling me.

So the basic, working algorithm is:

```
def rotate(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    # reverse rows
    matrix.reverse()

    # reflect
    start = 0
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(start, n):
            matrix[row][col], matrix[col][row] = matrix[col][row], matrix[row][col]
        start = start + 1
```

The idea is to pass a matrix defined as a list of lists, like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`.

Example input/output:

```
>>> some_matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> rotate(some_matrix)
>>> print(some_matrix)
[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Great. So, I was wondering if I could replace `matrix.reverse()` with something maybe a little more intuitive, like simply using slice indexing. So I wrote a new `rotate`, like this:

```
def rotate2(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    # reverse rows
    matrix = matrix[::-1]

    # reflect
    start = 0
    for row in range(n):
        for col in range(start, n):
            matrix[row][col], matrix[col][row] = matrix[col][row], matrix[row][col]
        start = start + 1
```

Which SHOULD give me the same results, based on:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b = a
>>> b = b[::-1]
>>> a.reverse()
>>> print(a)
[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> print(b)
[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> print(a==b)
True
```

However, when I use `rotate2` on the same input/output example, I get:

```
>>> some_matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> rotate2(some_matrix)
>>> print(some_matrix)
[[9, 6, 3], [8, 5, 2], [7, 4, 1]]
```

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I'm curious why you deem `[::-1]` to be more intuitive than `.reverse`. Anyone who understands english can envision what `.reverse` would do, however `[::-1]` would look weird for anyone not knowing slicing syntax

Comment: You see, I'm not a fan of remembering method names. Slice indexing on the other hand, is pretty "universal" jargon in terms of programming. But sure, the name `reverse` is definitely more intuitive. I guess it was just a programming study experiment after all. I'm still learning python :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matrix = matrix[::-1]` creates a new list and assigns it to the *local* name `matrix`; it does not modify the original list in-place.

`matrix.reverse()`, on the other hand, *does* modify the original list.

Consider these simple functions:

```
def r1(m):
    m = m[::-1]

def r2(m):
    m.reverse()

>>> x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> r1()
>>> x
[[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> r2()
>>> x
[[3,4],[1,2]]
```

Comment: But if that's the case, shouldn't I see something like [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] etc after using my function? Instead, I see [[9, 6, 3], [8, 5, 2], [7, 4, 1]]. I mean, because after that line `matrix = matrix[::-1]` wouldn't I be modifying the local name `matrix` and leaving the original `matrix` unmodified?

Comment: The loop modifies the *sublists*, but you are working with a different outer list in each function.

Comment: @eduardokapp just add `return matrix` to the end of your function.

Comment: @It_is_Chris that would not make my function modify the input in-place! Thanks for the suggestion, though.